# How to consolidate multiple project backlogs into one in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I am looking for a way in (or outside of) TFS to consolidate the backlog across two separate projects, as the consultants are the same across the projects - just how the projects were set up.

It would be best to consolidate the backlog/tasks AND resource capacities, as a way to see the information at a program or portfolio level.  Would anyone have a working solution, such as any code/query logic available from Microsoft or elsewhere that could do the trick?

The company is using TFS on the cloud, so may be fewer options.

Answer (score 3):

We decided to consolidate all our team projects into a single one. We used to have one team project per product but now we switched to one team/area per product.

It is much simpler to administrate, and so much more convenient when you need to extract some cross team/product reports.

We used to the TFS Integration Tool to consolidate work items and source code.